# Pass id value to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to pass the value of the id of `a` link tag in my jquery function but it's not working. Here are my codes,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var guyid = $('.guyid').attr('id');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventSources: ['json-script.php?id=guyid']
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<?php
    $result_guy = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM person");
    while ($row_guy=mysql_fetch_array($result_guy)) {
        echo '<a href="index.php" class="guyid" id="' .$row_guy[0]. '">' .$row_guy[1]. '</a><br>';
    }
?>
</body>
```

Is there something wrong in my code? How can I get the value of the id of `a` tag. Need this help badly. Tnx.

Comment: alert(guyid); gives correct value?

Comment: yes. I get the correct value according to `$row_guy[0]`

Comment: Where have you used that id which you passed

Comment: Remember, you will have multiple elements when you select with $('.guyid'). Your code should get the ID, but only for the top most element.

Comment: I want the value of the id according to the `a` link I click on.

Comment: @SinOscuras where is your `<?php ?>` tags ?

Answer (score 3):

instead

```
 eventSources: ['json-script.php?id=guyid']
```

try

```
eventSources: ['json-script.php?id='+guyid]
```

Comment: still not working. Iget results when I manually try like this, `json-script.php?id=1592`

Comment: Any error in console..? Do you have more than one `<a>` tag with class `guyid` ?

Comment: check alert(guyid) gives correct value,if so then try $.trim(guyid) and pass in eventSources

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var guyid = $('.guyid').attr('id');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
        eventSources: ['json-script.php?id=' + guyid] //<-- fix
    });
});
```

and You must know that the guyid just has **first** **a** tag's id always.
example,

```
<a href="index.php" class="guyid" id="1">1</a> 
<a href="index.php" class="guyid" id="2">2</a>
<a href="index.php" class="guyid" id="3">3</a>
<a href="index.php" class="guyid" id="4">4</a>
```

then, your guyid always has just **1**.
IF you want get all of ids, you have to use each loop.
ex.

```
 var arr = [];
 $('.guyid').each( function(idx, g) { 
  console.log( $(g).attr('id') );
  arr.push( $(g).attr('id') );
 });
```

and use the arr array at the eventSources.

look like this

```
   eventSources: ['json-script.php?id=' + arr.join()]
```

A ha, do you want make link when click the a tag?
Then,

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click( function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); //if you don't want to go index.php
            var guyid = $(event.target).attr('id');
            // or 
            //var guyid = event.target.id;

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            eventSources: ['json-script.php?id=' + guyid]
          });
        });
    });
```

I am sorry my poor English.
and I shall be happy if this help you, Tnx.

Comment: Tnx. But I want to go to `index` page everytime I click on link. Here I can only visit for one time.

Comment: where is `#calendar`? index.php?

Comment: Its after `<?php ?>` tag. I din't mention in my post.

Comment: In that case, guyid must be parameter!
so guyid=$_GET["guyid"];  use this variable at eventSources.